# AWS RDS Oracle and Data Changes/updates

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-sns

Can AWS Lambda connect to RDS Oracle database? Specifically, can updates/changes to data send a notification.

I've read about associating an SNS/Event Notification subscription and also about using Node-Oracledb, but nothing concrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can connect Oracle instance from lambda. For example, [node-oracledb-for-lambda](https://github.com/nalbion/node-oracledb-for-lambda) of Node.js. There is a little explanation on [this page](https://medium.com/@mitchplanck/aws-lambda-node-js-oracle-3b5806fbecd3).

Comment: with this lambda connection, can notifications/triggers be sent when there is data content changed or updated n the RDS ? Most examples I've seen only mention changes to the configuration/set-up of the RDS

Comment: Yes, this is what I am also specifically looking for. The many websites that show about RDS Oracle Event notification point to DB generic events and not at the table or schema level changes. How to go about that?